# Swift: If image exists, return it, otherwise return nil

Tags: image, if-statement, swiftui, symbols, exists

I've been trying to find a way to check if SF Symbols and Images exist in swift.
In all of the answers I've come across, the nil coalescing operator (`??`) is used, which requires a `default` image that always exists. This doesn't work in my case.

I would like to test if an image (or a symbol) exists and then return it if it exists, otherwise return `nil`.

How can this be achieved?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
I am trying to achieve this using `SwiftUI`'s `Image` for a multiplatform application. I am trying to avoid using `UIImage` or `NSImage` to do my checks.

**UPDATE 1**

Note 1:
When requesting an SF Symbol that does not exist (for example, there was a typo in the `systemName: [name]` parameter), the image appears as an empty area. (Tested with `Label`)

The following solutions have been tested and are ineffective:
(Note: in all of the attemps, there are is a variable `name: String`)

#### Solution 1

```
let image = Image(systemName: name)
if image {
    return image
} else {
    return nil
}
```

Throws the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected condition type 'Bool'

It throws the exact same error when: `let image = Image(name)`

#### Solution 2

```
if let image = Image(systemName: name) {
    return image
}
```

Throws the error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Image'

#### Solution 3

```
let image = Image(systemName: name)
if image != nil {
    return image
}
```

Does not work and gives the warning:

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'Image' to 'nil' always returns true

Comment: Just return the image from the symbol, it it exists it will be it, else it will be nil, no?

Comment: Maybe you should add some code to clarify your question. Btw, how can an SF Symbol not exists?

Comment: That is exactly what `image(named)` and `image(systemName)` already do, so what's the question?

Comment: Just remove the `??` nil coalescing operator and the `default` image

Comment: @Larme I can always return the image. But I am unable to check if it has found the symbol I requested.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If you request a symbol it cannot find (for example, there's a typo) it still returns the image but its blank.

Comment: @LeoDabus I wish it were that simple, but in that case I can no longer check if the image is `nil` or not.

Comment: You said you want to return nil in case it doesnt exist. Thats what it will do

Comment: @matt The question is how can I check if an image or symbol **exists**, in other words, it has been found and is not `nil`. If it is not found, there is an error in the console but it builds and runs and the area where the image was supposed to be is displayed but is left blank.

Comment: just check if it is not equal to nil. If it is not nil it exists.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have updated the question. Please ready my 3rd solution where it gives me a warning when I try to check if it is `nil`.

Comment: @Lae I didn't realize that it was a non fallible initializer. [UIKit initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3294233-init) would return nil. So just use it to check if it is nil or not `UIImage(systemName: "whatever") != nil`

Comment: Oooooh, you're talking about SwiftUI Image. That was not so clear from the original question. Always tag (as Leo Dabus has now done for you).

Comment: Misspelling a SF Symbol is something that should be discovered during testing and isn’t really a runtime issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, `Image.init(systemName:)` returns some sort of placeholder image if the name isn't recognized.

If you want to detect whether the name is recognized, you can try creating a `UIImage` with it. `UIImage.init?(systemName:)` returns `nil` if the name isn't recognized.

```
let image: Image? = UIImage(systemName: name)
    .map { Image(uiImage: $0) }
```

The above `Image` might behave differently in some ways than an image created with `Image(systemName:)`. I'm not sure. So you can do the following instead if that is a problem:

```
let image: Image? = UIImage(systemName: name)
    .map { _ in Image(systemName: name) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was already aware of this solution.However, in my case this is not optimal because I am using `SwiftUI`'s `Image`. The app is multiplatform and I am trying to avoid `NSImage` and `UIImage`.

Comment: I humbly suggest you use `#if os(macOS)` to handle the macOS case, and move on to more important work. :^)

Answer (score 2):

Following [@rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff)'s answer I ended up creating cases for the OS and then using concise checks to determine if an image exists and do logic.

In the end, I was able to avoid using `UIImage` or `NSImage` outside the actual check.
This is an unorthodox and inefficient approach, but this is what my code ended up like:

##### For Custom Images

```
#if os(macOS)
if (NSImage(named: name)) != nil {
    //image found, do some logic...
}
#elseif os(iOS)
if (UIImage(named: name)) != nil {
    //image found, do some logic...
}
#endif
```

##### For System Symbols

```
#if os(macOS)
if (NSImage(systemSymbolName: name, accessibilityDescription: "")) != nil {
    //image found, do some logic...
}
#elseif os(iOS)
if (UIImage(systemName: name)) != nil {
    //image found, do some logic...
}
#endif
```