# SwiftUI LabelStyle, testing if configuration.icon exists?

Tags: swiftui, ios17

In my App, I place a button with a gear symbol in the upper left corner; it is used to bring up a settings sheet.

```
Button { withAnimation { showSettingsSheet.toggle() }} label: {
  Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
}
```

In the first iOS 17 beta build, I've had reports that the Settings button did not display nor respond to taps. I didn't get a chance to try it myself, but I suspect that maybe the SF Symbol didn't load, and because I use a `.iconOnly` label style, there was nothing to display or respond to touches.  This is not a problem on iOS 17 beta 2.

I want to handle this more gracefully in the future. I think to create SafeIconOnlyLabelStyle that would normally display the icon but fall back to the configuration title.icon blank.

```
struct SafeIconOnlyLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
  @ViewBuilder func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    if configuration.icon == <<WHAT SHOULD configuration.icon BE COMPARED TO>> {
      Label(configuration)
        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
    } else {
      Label(configuration)
    }
  }
}
```

How can I check that `configuration.icon` exists and is valid?

**Update**

Unlike UIImage, NSImage, and CGImage, which return an Optional to test against, SwiftUI always returns an Image View.  If you pass a bad name to Image, it still adds an Image View to the hierarchy, just one with no height or width.

```
Label("Title", systemName: "badName")
```

and

```
Label { 
  Text("Title") 
} icon: {
    Image(systemImage: "badName")
}
```

are equivalent.  Running on iOS and using the `.titleAndIcon` LabelStyle, one might expect the equivalent to be:

```
HStack {
  Image(systemImage: "badName").frame(width: .zero, height: .zero)
  Text("Title")
}
```

When the `.iconOnly` LabelStyle is used, the simplified label would be just the icon, like so:

```
Image(systemImage: "badName").frame(width: .zero, height: .zero)
```

When this hierarchy is used for the Label of a Button, the Button is rendered with no title or icon.  This can be problematic if the source of the problem is out of your control.

My first solution was to create SafeIconOnlyLabelStyle that would use `GeometryReader` to calculate the size of the `configuration.icon` and display the `configuration.title` when the size was `.zero.`  That worked fine; however, it would be a potential source of future bugs if Apple decides to make changes.

Instead, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69351478/7915772), I created a custom SafeLabel View that uses the title instead of the icon when the icon does not exist.

```
public struct SafeLabel: View {
  #if os(macOS)
  typealias SystemImage = NSImage
  #elseif os(iOS)
  typealias SystemImage = UIImage
  #endif

  private var title: Text
  private var icon: Image?

  public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, systemImage name: String) {
    self.title = Text(titleKey)

    if let image = fetchImage(systemName: name) {
      #if os(macOS)
      icon = Image(nsImage: image)
      #elseif os(iOS)
      icon = Image(uiImage: image)
      #endif
    }
  }

  @MainActor public var body: some View {
    Label {
      title
    } icon: {
      if let icon {
        icon
      } else {
        Text("\(title)")
      }
    }
  }
    
  private func fetchImage(systemName name: String) -> SystemImage? {
    #if os(macOS)
    guard let image = NSImage(systemImageName: name) else { return nil }
    #elseif os(iOS)
    guard let image = UIImage(systemName: name) else { return nil }
    #endif
    return image
  }
}
```

This eliminates my concerns about preventing Labels (and Buttons) from disappearing if an Image is unavailable.

Comment: Isn't this something you should test during development? Once it is spelled correctly and does exist it will not change that state and will always work.

Comment: I don't show it in my example code, but the Label title and systemImage are semantic values; if I type those wrong, the project won't compile.  What I'm asking about is, how can I more gracefully deal with a situation where a system bug may prevent the Label from having a valid icon?